# Determine NSDate's season

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, foundation

I'm trying to write a category method that would tell me which season a given NSDate belongs to.
For example:

```
if ([myDate season] == dateSeasonWinter) {
     [self bringJacket]
}
```

The idea is very simple but the fact that it needs to be year agnostic make things a little more complex, but I can't figure out how to do it elegantly.

Comment: Have a look at `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`. Given a *calendar* and a *date*, you can compute the month, day of month, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Really cool idea, but you have to localize it in so many ways. Here is couple of examples I can think of:

- winter in Australia has different temperature comparing to winter in Europe
- according to [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Season), you have 6 different seasons in India oppose to 4 in Europe
- in some areas animals [can extend seasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punxsutawney_Phil)

So, again, it's a nice idea, but I think you have to refine the scope to make this task  feasible 
Straight forward implementation would be `switch` over `NSDateComponents` `month` property but I don't think that's what you're looking for:)

Comment: I was going to say something similar, though I think you mean when its summer in Australia its winter in Europe. I was also going to add that this method probable belongs on NSDateComponents instead of NSDate. The localised issue could be solve if you there was an easy way to find which side of the equator the location is. Alternatively instead of referring to seasons as summer, winter etc. you could just have a method that gives you a numerical value 0-3. 0 meaning the first season on the year which contains January and so forth.

Comment: Localization is also something I thought about and that's indeed adding to the very difficulty of this problem. For now I'll probably resort to a simple, extremely western world centric, system that just checks the months and on what hemisphere the user is to deduce a season. But that's exactly what I meant by inelegant...